# php codeigniter and new valum ajax upload

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, upload

I am trying to integrate new valum ajax upload with codeigniter 2.

However the new valum ajax upload is using $_GET to sent file name, while codeigniter 2 upload library always check fileupload using $_FILES.

How do i make it works with each other,

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Extended upload library. Create `MY_upload.php` file in your library and make your own function like `do_upload()`. For example `do_Vupload()`. And put valum codes inside it or load as another library or include it. There you have own upload method. And use it

```
$this->upload->do_Vupload();
```